# Linux : Send message when a user logs in

Tags: linux, shell

I must create a `Shell` that when a user logs in, it will print on the terminal from which the connection was made how many users are logged in an their number of processes.

The second part ( the one with processes ) was easy, thanks you the following command

```
ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c
```

But I can't go any further. I don't know how to automatically launch this script for every user, and even more, how to write on their terminal. ( I fount commands like `msg`, `write` but all require me to insert the username)

Comment: Probably more suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), or [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), but you should simply call a script from `/etc/profile` or the equivalent for the shells existing in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c` does not show count of processes of logged in users but of every user (including system accounts) not necessarily currently logged in.

List of only logged in users can be get with `who` command.

To get count of processed per logged in user one can try:

```
for u in `who -u | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort -u`; do echo -n "$u "; ps hx -u $u | wc -l; done;
```

Message displayed on users terminal only at login time is set in `/etc/motd` test file. This is static file. What you need is dynamically generated `motd` file. This can be achieved with `update-motd`.

On Ubuntu/Debian `update-motd` configuration scripts can be found in `/etc/update-motd.d/`

I'm not sure if similar feature is available on RedHat like systems but you can search for `update-motd` or dynamic motd.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message to appear only each time the user opens the terminal, you can edit /etc/bash.bashrc and include the .sh script from there. This file basically contains commands that get executed every time a terminal is opened.

Comment: I read about that, but since we are connecting to a station (server), I need to display the message only on the terminal from which the connection was made.

Comment: Starting a new shell is not the same as logging in!  There are many occasions to invoke Bash that are not logins, and users may have shells other than bash.